# Unable to print a list using join

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The following code throws an error.

```
squares = map(lambda a: a*a, [1,2,3,4,5])  
print "%d." %", ".join(squares)
```

How should I print it join? I want the result to be as 
1, 4, 9, 16, 25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
print "%d." %", ".join(squares)
```

to

```
print ", ".join(map(str, squares))
```

If you want to append a `.` to the end of line, use:

```
print '%s.'%", ".join(map(str, squares))
```

or simply `print ", ".join(map(str, squares))+'.'`.

And if you're using python3, `print` becomes a builtin *function* . Unpack your list and use `sep=','` as @Ashwini Chaudhary mentioned:

```
print(*squares, sep=', ')
```

[`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) returns a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the
iterable (`squares` in your example).

Comment: And for Python3: `print(*squares, sep=', ')` should do it.

Comment: @zhangxaochen : now it says `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found`

Comment: @mario23 if you want to add the period mark `.`, see my updates.